# DBpedia outdated data

Tags: dbpedia

I wanna know what is the purpose of using DBpedia (not DBpedia Live) knowing that the represented information is outdated?

For example, at the resource description http://dbpedia.org/page/United_States, `dbo: leader` has still the value of the precedent democratic administration (`dbr:Barack_Obama`, `dbr:John_Roberts`, `dbr:Joe_Biden`, `dbr:Paul_Ryan`)

Comment: "I wanna know" is rather demanding. You might consider adjusting your tone for future questions, perhaps just by dropping this phrase.

Comment: You can always download the latest dumps from DBpedia databus and load it into your local triple store. Nobody ever claimed that the public DBpedia endpoint is up to date nor for production use. It's a community service you're getting for free. Somebody else is paying for hosting the server. It's also likely, that organisations like Google, IBM Watson are able to load the latest dataset if they even still use DBpedia which I doubt.

Comment: So, if it's too old for your use case, use DBpedia Live or download the latest dumps, or even better, checkout the DBpedia extraction project from Github and let your infrastructure do the extraction and hosting of a local Virtuoso server.

Answer (score 1):

The data in the DBpedia Snapshot instance is generally static -- it doesn't change regularly. A query you write and execute today, right now, should produce the same results next week, tomorrow, or next year -- until the next refreshed dataset is loaded.

You can also reference a specific dataset, even after the data loaded into the public endpoint has changed. For instance, right now, the DBpedia Snapshot instance holds the 2016-10 dataset, which is the latest static dump.

On the other hand, the DBpedia Live instance is constantly changing -- fed by the Wikipedia changes firehose. A query you write and execute today, right now, may produce completely different results next week, tomorrow, an hour, or even a few minutes from now.

Each of these has value for different uses. Only you can decide whether your work is better suited to query execution on the Live or Snapshot endpoint.

Comment: According to Kingsley Uyi Idehen (CEO and Founder of OpenLink Software) Enterprises, such as Apple (via Siri), Google (via Freebase and Google Knowledge Graph), and IBM (via Watson) have used DBpedia in their projects, I'm wondering how did they got reliable data?

Comment: I work with Kingsley. My employer is OpenLink Software. The "reliability" of "reliable data" is in the eye of the beholder. The named enterprises have indeed used DBpedia for various projects in various ways. Such (few) details of those projects as I have are under NDA, so I cannot tell you whether they found static data (DBpedia Snapshot) or dynamic data (DBpedia Live) to be better for their purposes, nor what their definitions of "reliable" were.